# AngularJS: After $compile I get an infdig error on $rootscope

Tags: angularjs, compilation

I am simply trying to add a dynamic element to the end of a list but I want that dynamic element to be evaluated by Angular so that when it is clicked it can register an ng-click event. This works as expected but when I click it a second time I get an infdig error.

This may be important, not sure, the list it gets appended to is a list of links, they go to different pages in the application (using angularUI router) and those "pages" are in the same view so the page doesn't change just the content on the page. All of those "pages" use the same controller and template.

```
   feedbacklink = angular.element('<li><a ng-click="test()" id="reviewPageLink">Customer Feedback</a></li>');
   $('#section_2 ul').first().append(feedbacklink);
   $compile(feedbacklink)($scope);
```

The ng-click triggers (simplified to show the issue):

```
$scope.test = function () {
    alert('test');
};
```

It seems to me like the $compile is being called again but that doesn't seem to be the case when I put a console.log immediately following the compile, it only shows once. Is there a way to assure that compile only runs once, or is that not even the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an `ng-repeat` for this instead of doing manual DOM manipulation yourself?

Comment: Not sure how ng-repeat would fit in here. I have a dynamic list generated by an API call and then I am appending another element to that same list.

Comment: Seems this issue is bigger than I thought, I just got it when clicking a completely different link on the same page. Also found this bug report: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417

Comment: That bug report indicates the problem occurs when something is using the HTML5 History API. Is that true for your situation? Also, it would help to post the full infinite digests error message, as it should include the watch log that actually shows which watch expressions are dirty and keep being evaluated because they are always changing.

Comment: I have narrowed down this issue to using history.pushstate as noted in the link above. Switching to $location.path works to resolve the issue but it doesn't update the URL which is why I was using history.pushstate in the first place.

Comment: I am not sure why `$location.path()` is not updating the URL for you - my understanding was that it did, but I am not familiar with angularUI router, maybe it is different.